# yii2 validate empty dropdownlist, checkbox

Tags: forms, validation, yii2

i have certain fields as required in the model and they are dropdownlist on the form.

if i try to submit the form without selecting anything no validation error occurs on the view the way a textinput would.

**model**

```
[['name', 'survey_type','country_id'], 'required', 
                'isEmpty' => function ($value) {
                    return empty($value);
                }
            ],
```

display empty red validation

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255]) ?>
```

does not display any validation

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'survey_type')->dropDownList([$surveyTypeList],['prompt'=>'Select Survey Type','id'=>'Survey_Type_dropdown']) ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you overrided `id` for drop-down list:

```
'id' => 'Survey_Type_dropdown'
```

You shouldn't do that If you want client validation working for this field.

Ids generated automatically and then used in javascript related with `ActiveForm`.

Remove it and everything should be fine:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'survey_type')->dropDownList([$surveyTypeList],['prompt' => 'Select Survey Type']) ?>
```

If you want to do something with this element in javascript, use auto generated id or assign custom class.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because when the value is empty you return the result of `empty($value)` so the the attribute is set to true or false, meaning it is not empty.

Try removing the isEmpty part.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works, however, it isn't the correct answer.  You may need to change the ID of any given input field and just telling people not to do it because they will not retrain client validation isn't true.

As per the Yii2 API docs it states that if you change the ID of an input field you must also update the input property "selector" as well to match the new ID you specified in the "options" property of the input field.

You do this as follows:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'survey_type', ['selectors' => ['input' => '#Survey_Type_dropdown']]))->dropDownList([$surveyTypeList],['prompt'=>'Select Survey Type','id'=>'Survey_Type_dropdown']) ?>
```

Creating the input like above will allow you to change the ID of an input field while retaining client validation.